# Xcode does not support USDZ file format

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, usdz

I can't view USDZ files in my Xcode. I downloaded some of the models provided by apple in AR Quick Look Gallery, but when I am not able to view the in the Xcode (Image 1).
Also, I can't convert the usdz file to ARScene in Xcode (Image 2).
[When I try to view the USDZ file on Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR0Ur.jpg)
[When I try to convert the USDZ file in Xcode project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itP23.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a question to go along with this statement?

Comment: Yes, I am still looking for a way to convert my USDZ file to a scene file (.scn), so I can use it in my AR app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was with my OS version. After I updating my mac to Mojave, I am able to preview USDZ files and also I am able to convert them to SceneView in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use brand-new `USDZ` file format in RealityKit or in SceneKit's `Scene graph`, and to use *command line tool's* conversions via `usdzconvert` or `xcrun` commands, you need **Xcode 11** or higher for RealityKit, or **Xcode 10** or higher for SceneKit, and, of course, **Swift 5** to be installed on MacOS Catalina or macOS Mojave.

Comment: @zyonneo https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/28/pixars-universal-scene-description-for-unity-out-in-preview/